# How to properly type a custom selector function, which picks properties from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was creating a `useReduxState` hook, which made use of Redux's `useSelector` and lodash's `pick` module. I've simplified my approach for the sake of brevity for this question. Here is what I have:

```
interface IReducerA {
    loading: boolean
}

interface IReducerB {
    open: boolean
}

type TGetReducerState = IReducerA & IReducerB;

interface IState {
    reducerA: IReducerA;
    reducerB: IReducerB;
}

const state = {
    reducerA: { loading: false; },
    reducerB: { open: true; }
}

const getState = (reducer: keyof IState, values: Array<keyof TGetReducerState>): TGetReducerState => pick(state, values);

const { loading } = getState('reducerA', ['loading'])
```

I've managed to get this working (kind of). The last line,

```
const { loading } = getState('reducerA', ['loading'])
```

correctly suggested `'loading'` as one of the entries to `values: Array<keyof TGetReducerState>` and it correctly suggests `'loading'` as one the return values.

The problem here, is that Typescript would not complain about the following line:

```
const { loading } = getState('reducerA', ['open'])
```

There are two problems with this line. The first is that the property `'open'` does not exist in `reducerA` and the second problem is that if I request `'open'`, then I shouldn't be able to destructure `const { loading } = . . .`.

How can I properly type this?

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKYCgBmBXZAY0nlWVAAd4iBrAClQCMArTEgGlFswE9oAlKADe2UKBAQYCFBhziskfOgo9+AOiwATfEUz1GrLmqEBeAHwix48fFyhDbEqABkL0AHlW7SOsrpUSEDeSkx1AAsAQ2gPAHdkAAUA0PRIXnUiSIAbLMcfYz4BIVEbUtBmFgBtNQBdUFNy7xJqvhqAbmsbAF9OhUwlFUaWDu6uYS6BDp7seGRITHRcSL1QAEkAJUwdPXQAQStSrNRIrVnEAC5QJlRULMxI5Gxp2fnF5cw1ze2FgCEDm1QoWQl2ut3uj2maVCoAAKgBxfpfXQLADKkEi83qny2yL2rmx33QPw6MzmCyWK1WaIxH1EAEhtLjdpcNjidrsOgy2b8WUidsSnthsERyNBIKAxTSsSUbIz2ZdhKAjiczpcllloB8uhxenKeSJykDLpB0PgtTrpiLkGLQIh+tTMQ16Hr0Jc1Kh7FT0fMuAA3bJm6CXXbodCRXgAHnd9nhiO56AdmHMAkuscgfNR3o+FioNAYkvmlRdNT9AcwghJVptiuVp2QiFAXSxdsgifoAHIXbt21xKu3a2d2zUBEA) is my approach.

## Edit

Writing here, because it's too long for the comment section.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64884185/2891356) approach [doesn't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=9&pln=34&pc=16#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)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE. Full version**

```js
function pick<T extends TGetReducerState, V extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(object: T, keys: V):Pick<T, V[number]> {
    return keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
        if (object && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
            // I made here small improvement, because I prefer to not mutate accumulator argument in reduce function
            return {
                ...obj,
                [key]: object[key]
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }, {} as Pick<T, V[number]>);
}

interface IReducerA {
    loading: boolean;
    age: number;
}

interface IReducerB {
    open: boolean
}

type TGetReducerState = IReducerA | IReducerB;

interface IState {
    reducerA: IReducerA;
    reducerB: IReducerB;
}

const state: IState = {
    reducerA: { loading: false, age: 0 },
    reducerB: { open: true },
}

const getState = <T extends keyof IState, V extends keyof IState[T]>(reducer: T, values: V[]) => pick(state[reducer], values)


const { loading, age } = getState('reducerA', ['loading', 'age'])
const { open } = getState('reducerA', ['loading', 'age']) // error
```

Comment: Ok, I will take a look a bit later

Comment: @Mike K Do you mean, it does not work without @ts-ignore?

Comment: I mean that TS does not complain about `const { open } = getState('reducerA', ['loading'])` (`open` does not exist on `reducerA`)

Comment: Btw, +1 for using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` ))

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! Quick question, while you took a stab at it -- what would be the return type of function `pick`? Lint is complaining, and I tried making it `keyof TGetReducerState`, but that didn't work

Comment: Added return type

Comment: Where did you add the return type? Is `<T extends keyof IState, V extends keyof IState[T]>` the return type for getState? Sorry, a little new to typescript

Comment: No problem. I added `Pick<T, V[number]>` to `pick` function. The very first line

Comment: I see. Shouldn't `useReduxState` hook see this return type? I was interested in such a hook and I found your answer on Google, so I copied and pasted your answer, but I'm getting a [typescript error](https://i.imgur.com/Y8XgGKs.png)

Comment: @displayName I got it. Pease use this piece of code `const getState = <T extends keyof IState, V extends keyof IState[T]>(reducer: T, values: V[]): ReturnType<typeof pick> => pick(state[reducer], values)`